# Iterator invalidation in boost::unordered_map

Tags: c++, boost, unordered-map

I am using `boost::unordered_map` as follows

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<WriterExeciter> PtrWriter;
typedef std::list<PtrWriter> PtrList; 
boost::unordered_map<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned long long>, PtrList>  Map
Map instrMap;
```

Now I am making some changes to the list of type `PtrList` in a loop

```
for(auto it = instrMap.begin(); it != instrMap.end(); ++it)
{
     auto key = it->first();
     auto list& = it->second();    
     //Make some change to an element in list 

      if(list.empty())
      {
            instMap.erase(key); 
      }



}
```

1. Does making changes to the list invalidate the iterator to instrMap?
2. Erasing the element will invalidate the iterator pointing to the erased element. How do I modify my code so that the this does not cause any problem? Does using `it++` instead of `++it` help?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `erase()` operation will invalidate the iterator. However, it also returns a valid iterator to the next element.  So you can use something like the following:

```
for(auto it = instrMap.begin(); it != instrMap.end();)
{
     auto key = it->first();
     auto list& = it->second();    
     //Make some change to an element in list 

      if(list.empty())
      {
            it = instMap.erase(it); 
      }
      else {
            ++it;
      }
}
```

Comment: I looked into the documentation. It should be instMap.erase(it) instead of instMap.erase(key). The second expression returns the number of elements erased.

Comment: @sank: you're right - that was a careless copy/paste error. Fixed.