# c++ boost map program crash after erase

Tags: c++, boost

I have a problem and dont know how to proper solve it or WHY the error appear.

To my problem:
I have 1 loop which execute a function every 2 seconds. That functions does a for() function and erase all entrys which remaining time is at 0. If remaining time is not 0 then it will decrease it by 2000 (2sec).

But after erasing an entry the program crashes...

boost map:

```
boost::unordered_map<unsigned int, sBUFF_INFO*> p_BuffInfo;
```

function which get executed from 2 seconds loop

```
void CSkill::DecreaseAllBuffRemTime()
{
    for( itertype(p_BuffInfo) it = p_BuffInfo.begin(); it != p_BuffInfo.end(); it++ )
    {
        sBUFF_INFO* buff = it->second;
        if(buff != NULL)
        {
            if(buff->dwTimeRemaining <= 0)
            {
                this->DelPcBuffInfo(buff->tblidx)
            }else{
                buff->dwTimeRemaining -= 2000;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

DelPcBuffInfo function:

```
void CSkill::DelPcBuffInfo(unsigned int tblidx)
{
    p_BuffInfo.erase(tblidx);
}
```

Now after DelPcBuffInfo gets executed the program crash.

At this line it crash:

```
sBUFF_INFO* buff = it->second;
```

At debug:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00578e0f in GameServer.exe: 0xC0000005:
>   Access violation reading location 0xddddddd9.

it + node_ = hash_ CXX0030; Error: expression cannot be evaluated

I dont really understand why this error appear..

edit:
If I add a "return" after this->DelPcBuffInfo(buff->tblidx) then the program dont crash..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void CSkill::DecreaseAllBuffRemTime()
{
    auto it = p_BuffInfo.begin();
    while( it != p_BuffInfo.end() )
    {
        sBUFF_INFO* buff = it->second;
        if(buff)
        {
            if(buff->dwTimeRemaining <= 0)
            {
                // probably delete buff too
                it = p_BuffInfo.erase(it);
            } else {
                buff->dwTimeRemaining -= 2000;
                ++it;
            }
        } else {
            ++it;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding or removing items from a container will often invalidate your iterators. Check the documentation for unordered_map iterators or here: [Iterator invalidation in boost::unordered_map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11443405/iterator-invalidation-in-boostunordered-map)

Answer (score 1):

the correct idiom is

```
for( itertype(p_BuffInfo) it = p_BuffInfo.begin(); it != p_BuffInfo.end(); )
{
    sBUFF_INFO* buff = it->second;
    if(buff != NULL)
    {
        if(buff->dwTimeRemaining <= 0)
        {
            it = this->DelPcBuffInfo(buff->tblidx)
        }else{
            buff->dwTimeRemaining -= 2000;
            it++;
        }
    }
}
```

ie dont increment in the loop. Instead increment if you dont delete otherwise have the delete operation return the new iterator. Thats why remove returns an iterator pointing at the next element

This is courtesy of the awesome Scott Myers

Comment: thanks. Error at this line it = this->DelPcBuffInfo(buff->tblidx). "No operator found which akes a right-hand operand of type 'void'

Comment: this idiom is for erase on the iterator, wich is not what he is doing

Comment: delxxx smell like erase and the title says "c++ boost map program crash after erase"

Comment: @pm100 he does erase on key, that returns count

Comment: it also gets stuck in infinite loop if `buff==NULL`

Answer (score 1):

To add to the existing answers pointing out the erase-iterator idiom: The reason for you crash is that the iterator `it` is invalidated due to the removal of the element. Thus, the increment on the (invalid) operator causes undefined behaviour and it will point to some arbitrary memory block. Dereferencing the "iterator" then crashes your program.

To avoid this problem, apply the idiom as demonstrated in the other answers, that is
 * Use the iterator version of `erase`. It returns an iterator to the *next* element ( which may be `end()`)
 * Use the return value of this `erase` as new value of `it`. Since it already points to the next element, do *not* increment again (otherwise you may skip an element in your map or cause undefined behaviour if `it` already points to the end of the map.
 * Only increment the iterator yourself, when you did *not* erase an element.

**Note:** If your intention is to get rid of the `sBUFF_INFO` element completely upon removal from the map, your programm shows a memory leak. Erasing the pointer from the map does not delete the pointed-to memory. You need to delete the pointee yourself (or use an appropriate smart pointer).